# Jupyter notebook does not open Box folder

Tags: macos, jupyter, apple-m1

Running macOS Monterey 12.3 Apple M1 Pro, and opening Jupyter either through terminal (jupyter notebook) or Anaconda. When the http://localhost:8888/tree pulls up I only see some of my folders & most importantly I don't see by Box (box.com) and I cannot access it at all. I cannot even access my Users account. Any advice?

[image]

I have tried navigating all the available folders with no success.

Answer (score 3):

I got into same issue when I upgrade my OS from catalina to Monterey.
I did some research today and found that it is because Box changes from kernel mode to FPE mode and causes this mount issue.

Some argues they can resolve this issue by deleting the FPE folder in content package.link:https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4413563848851-How-can-I-change-FPE-mode-to-Kernel-mode-

If this works for you then go for it.

Mine is OS monterey and it is not working. What I do to resolve this:

1. make an alias manually by run this in terminal:
   ln -s  ~/Library/CloudStorage/Box-Box ~/Box

This make an Box folder:

2. then allow access of Box in systems preferences/Security&privacy:
   I allowed full disk access to anaconda and it works.
   Also fizilla can access box as well

Good luck!

Comment: Making an alias and allowing full disk access to anaconda resolve my issue!